# Is the total transform of a point $x$ via a birational map of normal fibered surfaces always irreducible?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f : X\cdots\rightarrow Y$ be a birational map of normal fibered surfaces over a Dedekind scheme $S$. This means that $X$ and $Y$ are normal integral schemes of dimension 2, flat and projective over $S$.

Let $Z\subset X\times_S Y$ be the graph of $f$ (ie, the closure of the graph of $f$ restricted to a domain of definition), and $p_11 : Z\rightarrow X$, $p_2 : Z\rightarrow Y$ the projections.

For any closed point $x\in X$, the closed subset $p_2(p_1^{-1}(x))$ of $Y$ is called the "total transform of $x$ by $f$".

Is it clear that total transforms are always irreducible?

This seems to be implied by Proposition 8.3.22 and the proof of Lemma 9.2.1 of Qing Liu's "Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves".

Comment: I think that $Z$ should be the closure of the graph of $f$. Otherwise $p_1^{-1}(x)$ will be empty at points where $f$ is not defined.

Comment: @bertram That's a good point, though usually the graph of a birational map is defined to be this closure - after all, a birational map is an equivalence class of maps defined on open subsets!

Comment: Fair enough; I just wanted to check we are talking about the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is true. Let $X$ be a conic bundle over $S=\mathbf P^1$ that has e.g. one singular point $x$ of type $A_2$. Let $\phi: Y \rightarrow X$ be the minimal resolution, and $f=\phi^{-1}$.

Then if I am not mistaken $Z \cong Y$ and so the total transform of $x$ is the exceptional set of the resolution. But this is reducible.

Comment: Yes that seems to be right, though I really don't understand what Qing Liu is trying to say here... In Prop 8.3.22 he really says "if $\xi$ is **the** generic point of $f(x)$", and the proof of Lemma 9.2.1 claims that the total transform is a *prime divisor*.